# How do you define an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, deleted-comments

Here are two comments get deleted because of "being answers" in [Why aren't superbugs weaker than their wild type?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/3777/99)

[image: image description]

First, I want to say that I don't have any objection on deleting answers in comment. It's inconvenient, but it's necessary. However, I don't think that these two comments are answers.

1. The first one is classified as [implying an answer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25604492#25604492). Carey is surprise because he is reading something unbelievable ("I don't understand your reasoning..."), and asking for clarification. Asking for clarification can be in calm tone ("Why do you think this?") or in surprise tone ("What? Why do you think this?"). The latter can imply an answer, but first and foremost it is a way to showing expression, and I don't think it is an answer. Even I, the asker, cannot think it is an answer.
2. The second one answers on my previous comment ("why do I get downvoted?"). As YviDe saying below, it is to answer **a comment**, a thing that doesn't relate to the question. Yes, it is an answer, but it's an off-topic answer. Even if it will be used later to the on-topic final answer, in this form it is still a comment more than an answer, and shouldn't be deleted.
3. Talking about off-topic answers, what if they are there to answer an example? Say I give an example to back up my thinking, but unfortunately use it wrong. Would someone answers on that example only violate the policy? After all, it's just a minor answer which doesn't answer my major question, which is lying on the title. Writing it in the answer section seems to be off-topic.

One more thought. We can see that some users are not happy with this site. I think it is because of this policy: their contributions get deleted. We should be clear on what is an answer and what is a comment.

What do you think?

Comment: "The second one is indeed an answer, answering a logical process, so I don't object the deletion" Well, I certainly didnt mean it to be. I didn't provide the context, but it was in response to you asking why this was downvoted, so I gave one possible reason for that: a part of the question, for me, didn't make sense (didn't downvote, but almost did exactly for that reason). I did later use that sentence in my answer, but I don't really think "your question is wrong" is a good and complete answer.

Comment: very well. I have edited my post. Thanks

Comment: I have delayed answering this question for several reasons. One is that comments do not exist in isolation, and I do not want to discuss users here. Meta is generally for issues, not users. Another is that [comments](http://health.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) have been discussed, as well as [answers in comments](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/378/169). That you're the OP doesn't have any bearing on what constitutes an answer.

Comment: @anongoodnurse but I don't discuss about users?

Comment: You specifically included comments of *users* as the basis for your question. As I said, comments don't exist in isolation. Meta already has sufficient discussion on this issue.

Comment: @anongoodnurse that's just an example to illustrate my argument. My argument doesn't talk about any user. I do mention about me, Carey and YviDe, but that just for references, not to talk about their behaviors. And as I argue, the meta doesn't have sufficient discussion in these specific cases.

Comment: It should go without saying that anyone can answer this question. If users feel the need for discussion of this issue, they should feel free to post.

Comment: @anongoodnurse of course, I guess? Isn't that anyone should feel free to post?

Comment: @Ooker The policy on comment deletion has been quite random since the beginning. E.g. http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/392/43 ,  http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/302/43 , http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/327/43 etc. Is this comment going to be deleted? No idea. Good luck!